# why do I need to use .Net framework to implement json rpc using c#?

Tags: c#, json

sorry for asking this basic question. 
I'm trying to implement json rpc using c# and there are many examples.
but I still can not understand how it works.
send request encoded json and receive respond. that's all?
why do i need .Net? and what function is .Net work in implementation of json rpc?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need .NET to implement json rpc. However if you want your client to be written in C#, C# requires .NET.

If you don't want to use .NET you must choose another language to write your client in than C#.